# QML Image not displaying in Application

Tags: python, qml, pyqt5, qqmlapplicationengine

I am having trouble displaying a simple image into my application.
Here's the main.py:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtQml import QQmlApplicationEngine
from PyQt5.QtGui import QGuiApplication
from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject, QUrl


if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.argv += ['--style', 'material']
    app = QGuiApplication(sys.argv)
    engine = QQmlApplicationEngine('basic.qml')
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

And the basic.qml:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 2.1
import QtQuick.Controls.Material 2.1

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 200
    height: 400
    title: qsTr("Hello World")
    Material.theme: Material.Light
    Material.accent: Material.Orange
    Column {
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        Button {
            width: 200; height:50;
            font.capitalization: Font.MixedCase
            text: qsTr("Button Name")
            objectName: "button_obj_name"
            highlighted: true
            Material.background: Material.Orange

        }
        Image{
                width: 100; height: 100
                fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectFit
                source: "logo_name.jpg"
            }
    }
}
```

In the application window it seems that space is allocated but nothing is displaying.
[logo_name.jpg is located in the same folder where basic.qml and main.py are in ]

Comment: Can you try adding `sourceSize.width: 100; sourceSize.height: 100;` in the image?  `Image` has this weird `sourceSize` property...

Comment: to me it works correctly, you could explain how you execute your application.

Comment: As a sanity check can you please post the image you're trying to display & image/listing of folder contents?

Comment: @eyllanesc I'm running it directly from IDLE (F5) and I tried creating an executable with cx_freeze and the image is still not showing.

Comment: @Jason R. Mick I think you might be right. I've tried with a random logo from the internet and it displayed correctly.
 http://brandmark.io/logo-rank/random/pepsi.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It had something to do with the image I was trying to display(as @Jason R. Mick mentioned),I believe that the image I was trying to use was converted by changing it's extension name.

> As a sanity check can you please post the image you're trying to
>   display & image/listing of folder contents? – Jason R. Mick

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks right.  I was having a similar problem on my windows box.  Code that worked on the raspberry did not work on the windows machine.  Removing and reinstalling PyQt5 go it working again.

```
pip3 uninstall pyqt5
```

Answer (score 0):

You should better check current path.
You can print out the current path with `sys.argv[0]`.
After getting the path, copy your image file to that path.
Then, run again.

I also think this is not a problem of source code, but development environment.